# nodejs MEAN.io custom error logger

Tags: node.js, error-handling, mean.io

There is no information in MEAN.io documentation of how to implement custom error logger. The logger needs to be added AFTER the express router(app.router) and BEFORE any of my custom error handlers.

So how I can add my own logger to be after app.router attached?